# Verbs of perception with "dass" and "wie" as subjunctions - type of subjunction?

Tags: conjunction

In

> Ich hörte, wie er angelaufen kam.
> Ich hörte, dass er angelaufen kam.

we can use "wie" as well as "dass". Which type of subjunction would you categorize it as?

The Duden grammar labels "dass" as "neutral subjunction" in this usage:

> Ich wusste, dass er angelaufen kam.

Is it the same usage as above with "hören"? Is "wie" a neutral subjunction, too, then?

Comment: When referring to something the Duden grammar says, it would be useful to include the edition as well as the page or paragraph number.

Comment: @DavidVogt 2009, Number 1686

Answer (score 0):

The subjunction *wie* leads an adverbial clause that tells a manner, while the subjunction *dass* usually leads an object clause. The latter is “neutral” as an object gets its meaning only from the verb it relies on.

Often both clause options are possible but they have a different meaning:

> Ich wusste, dass er angelaufen kam. ← This is about the fact that
> he came.
>
> Ich wusste, wie er angelaufen kam. ← This is about the manner in which he came.

But *dass* can actually also lead a causal adverbial clause. It's not “neutral” then:

> Er rannte so schnell, dass er den Zug noch erreicht.
>
> Er rannte so schnell, damit er den Zug noch erreicht.

Those two are not fully identical in meaning but almost. The variant with *dass* gives both a reason and a conclusion. He has reached that train. The variant with *damit* does not tell the conclusion.

Comment: Thanks!
Is "wie er angelaufen kam" not an object clause? "Ich wusste" is not a complete sentence, right?

Comment: You could say *Ich wusste von der Art und Weise seines Kommens.* and explain that this is a prepositional object of the phrasal verb *von etwas wissen*, and that the clause replaced that prepositional object. But I would stick to the term *adverbial clause* because as soon you have an accusative object the same kind of clause explains that object instead of being an object itself, e.g. *Ich wusste die Art und Weise, wie er angelaufen kam.* You can't do that trick with the clause lead by *dass*. Because that one is truly an object clause.

Comment: It would be a bit strange for “wusste” and it can be regional, but to me “ich hörte, wie er angelaufen kam” can also just mean “I heard him come running”. (I am not quite sure in my English formulation here.)

Comment: "Er rannte so schnell, daß ..." is not causal but final.